# Excel formula - Compare two tables for values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help setting up an Excel-Formula.

I have two tables that I need to compare in order to multiply the *currency rate* of **table2** with the *amount* of **table1** depending on the *date* of **table1** matching the *date* field of **table2**.

If you have a look at the screenshot I made I think you will understand what I want to do: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdhDx.png)

Hope you can help me set up a formula for this. If you need the excel-file for testing I uploaded it to **zoho**. [Link](https://public.sheet.zoho.com/public/tonyclifton77/excelcurrency)

Comment: I almost have a suitable answer ;)

Comment: @t.thielemans I have a working answer now, but I'll hold back if you're close to one :)

Comment: Could you post it? :) I almost have it, but my cell won't display the correct value, whereas my formula result does ... `=INDEX($C$2:$E$13;MATCH(1;(B3=$C$2:$C$13)*(A3=$D$2:$D$13);0);3)` this display 1,31 which is correct but the cell is #N/A

Comment: @t.thielemans Did you enter it as an array formula? I just tried yours and it works for me (after replacing the semicolons with commas).

Comment: @RocketDonkey, Yes I always select that option when I configure the formula.

Comment: @t.thielemans Where does it display the correct answer?

Comment: @RocketDonkey, I select the cell and click the fx button, then choose 'array' and in the next screen left bottom and in the middle.

Comment: @t.thielemans Ahh, gotcha (forgot that existed :) ). Try clicking in the cell itself and then pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Comment: @RocketDonkey, nope still nothing :P

Comment: @t.thielemans Hmm, weird - and you're doing that just on the cell itself, not using the Fx button? Just clicking in the formula and hitting `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`? I'll post mine since I need to get to bed, but will definitely vote for yours once you get it working (since it revolves around the same concept anyway :) ).

Comment: So technically this works for you? `=A2*=INDEX($C$2:$E$13;MATCH(1;(B2=$C$2:$C$13)*(A2=$D$2:$D$13);0);3)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18277/discussion-between-rocketdonkey-and-t-thielemans)

Comment: @RocketDonkey, Omg I got it .. was clicking the in cell ... My bad!

Comment: @t.thielemans Haha, nice! Post it up!

Comment: @RocketDonkey, thank you very much for that :) What does the Ctrl+Shift+Enter do then?

Comment: @t.thielemans Turns it into an array formula - see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx for a good primer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=IF(ISNA(A3*INDEX($F$2:$H$13,MATCH(1,(B3=$G$2:$G$13)*(C3=$F$2:$F$13),0),3)),A3,A3*INDEX($F$2:$H$13,MATCH(1,(B3=$G$2:$G$13)*(C3=$F$2:$F$13),0),3))
```

Select your cell and put your cursor in the formula bar and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

PS: thanks to RocketDonkey ;)

Comment: Make sure to mention that it needs to be entered with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` :)

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of showing various ways, here is alternative using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=A2*SUMPRODUCT(--($F$2:$F$13=C2),--($G$2:$G$13=B2),$H$2:$H$13)
```

If you wanted to handle `0` values differently, you could wrap everything in an `IF` statement.

```
=IF(A2*SUMPRODUCT(--($F$2:$F$13=C2),--($G$2:$G$13=B2),$H$2:$H$13)=0,
  "Special stuff",
  A2*SUMPRODUCT(--($F$2:$F$13=C2),--($G$2:$G$13=B2),$H$2:$H$13))
```

[image]